# Command to remove computer from non-existant domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, command-line-interface

I lost my domain controller machine, and then add new domain controller but with a new  domain. How do I remove network machines from old domain using command line and add to new domain? Machines using Windows Server 2008 Core (command line only)

```
net computer \\name del
```

works only on domain controller.

```
sconfig
```

When I try to exit from old domain, console requests username and password for exit. I type it, and then get error "Could not connect to domain" (old domain controller not exists)

What to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `netdom remove computername /Domain:domain /UserD:user /PasswordD:* /Force`

Type `netdom remove /?` for the full command usage. The **/Force** option is what you're looking for. Per the help:

`Forces the unjoin of the machine from the domain even if the domain is not found or does not contain the matching computer object.`

To join the members to the new domain: `netdom join computername /Domain:domain /UserD:user /PasswordD:*`

Again type `netdom join /?` for help with the command usage.

Comment: For those of you lacking the netdom executable, this can be installed as part of the [RSAT (W8.1)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39296)  / [RSAT (W7)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7887) package. Download, install, then go to _Control Panel_ > _Turn Windows features on or off_. Under RSAT select _AD DS Snap-ins and Command-line Tools_ as per [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ZMfGPqU.png).

Comment: What's the point of the `/domain` etc? `netdom remove computername /force` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: `netdom remove computername /force` is sufficient!

Comment: this was the only way i was able to get ansible to unjoin a pc from domain after it lost its security ids for the name, somehow it wasnt fully joined.  awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more modern approach to this uses Powershell:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-computer?view=powershell-5.1#example-3--remove-computers-from-a-workgroup-without-confirmation