# Reset Admin Pass - Domain Controller Gone

Tags: windows, password

I am not a Microsoft person and I need to maintain some old servers.

The Domain Controller was removed from the network a while back and a Windows Server 2008 R2 is running a very important database.  For security reasons we need to change the Admin password but get an error saying that it cannot connect to the DC.

I really don't care to have a DC for this computer, I just want to change the Admin pass.

Is there any way to remove the computers requirement to have a DC?  Can we just change it to have a localized authentication?

I know the current domain/admin pass and CAN log in (cached), but I cannot change the password.

Comment: 1) Are you trying to change the local windows administrator password? 2) Is the computer still showing as a member of the domain? 3) Are you logging in as the local administrator account or the domain administrator account?

Comment: Are you changing a database user password? It may be giving you a hard time because the database user itself is tied to the domain, not the server.

Comment: I am Logging in as domain/administrator.  just administrator does not work. 
Unfortunately, people can still remotely login as domain/administrator and i need to lock this baby down.

Comment: "Are you changing a database user password?"
No sir, the main login needs to be changed.

Comment: `I know the current admin pass and can log in` Are you sure about that?  Because you describe logging in with a *domain* administrator account, not a local one.

Comment: Must be a cached domain/admin credential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable the local administrator account. You can fire up lusrmgr.msc (Local users and groups) and then either enable/create a local administrator account. Then go through the disjoin process, otherwise you'll be high and dry when it comes to logging in locally.

Here's a link to technet on the detailed steps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770642.aspx

Comment: I will try that.  I find it weird that domain/administrator works even though the DC has been in the trash for a long time.

Comment: That is strange, but domain credentials can stay cached for quite some time in the absense of a domain to connect to. Since there's no authority to check in with it could just be orphaned with the old password forever, which is why you should get it disjoined ASAP

Comment: Also, if you do have MSSQL server running, make sure you add the local account as a server administrator to SQL before you disjoin. Going into single user mode on MSSQL can be a bit of a pain after the fact.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it sounds like the machine has cached credentials which are allowing users to login with `domain\administrator`.  That's why users can login, but you can't change it - loging in can be done with cached credentials, changing a domain password requires connectivity to a domain controller.

Probably the quickest way to remediate this is to unjoin the computer from the domain. Make sure you have the (or a) local administrator's credentials before doing that, though.

As noted in other answers, the command is `netdom remove computername /Domain:domain /UserD:user /PasswordD:* /Force`.  You can also do so through the computer properties, `Computer name, domian and workgroup settings` by changing the computer's domain from the domain it's on to any workgroup name you fancy.

If you don't have local administrator credentials, there are a couple ways to reset a password on a Windows machine.

One is to use a utility like the ["Ultimate Boot CD"](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3064) - boot the machine to CD, and select the NT password rest tool. The other popular, native option is to use your [Windows install CD to enter a recovery console, swap `cmd.exe` with `utilman.exe`, reboot, and launch the ease-of-use/accessibility tool, which has been replaced with cmd.exe](https://4sysops.com/archives/forgot-the-domain-admin-password/).  You can then reset the password with `net user`.  Don't forget to switch `cmd.exe` and `utilman.exe` back once you're done.

Finally, it's bad practice to log in with the default administrator password, in general.  (It's like using `root` in Linux-land, but less excusable.  In Windows-land, best practice is to disable or rename the default Administrator user.)  Extra bad to do so with the default domain administrator password, and extra, extra bad to have a bunch of users logging on with the default domain administrator password.  Your next order of business after fixing this issue is to fix your policies, ASAP.

Comment: +1 for bothering to actually type this out for the OP.  You're being pretty kind today! :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.  I will +1 when I get 15 reps.  I appreciate all the help.  I've steered clear of Windows servers for too long, apparently.

Answer (score -1):

The answer might depend on what situation is in your site regarding domains, after that DC was removed. Do you have another DC? Are you required to have that server on a domain?

**Make sure you have a local admin password before continuing** (that is not clear from your question, you just say "I know the current admin pass and can log in", you don't specify if it is local or domain admin).

**If disjoining from the domain is appropriate**, you could use

`netdom remove computername /Domain:domain /UserD:user /PasswordD:* /Force`

Type `netdom remove /?` for the full command usage. The **/Force** option is what you're looking for. Per the help:

`Forces the unjoin of the machine from the domain even if the domain is not found or does not contain the matching computer object.`

The logic is that after disjoining the domain, you should be able to change the password without contacting any domain controller.

Credits: got this answer from user `mweisel` [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/412263/command-to-remove-computer-from-non-existant-domain).

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea, since he doesn't know the local administrator password, isn't it?

Comment: I edited my answer to alert to that situation, thank you. But the question itself should probably be edited too, it's dubious.

Comment: Cool. I don't suppose people are going to come back here and undo their downvotes on my answer, but that's ok, I can live with a couple of downvotes to teach me to be more thorough! :-)